# Google Script - Compare part of a file name to a subfolders name and move file to subfolder if there is a match

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Thanks to the awesome people on here I have a script that is cross checking file names with folder names and moving the file to the folder if the name matches (code below)

What I'm struggling with now if searching the subfolder of a certain folder and checking the files to see if part of the name matches the subfolder name

e.g

Folders:

Folder name: example1
Subfolder name: example1-commercial
Subfolder name: example1-clients

Files:
example1-commercial.pdf (move to example1-commercial folder)
example1-clients.pdf (move to example1-clients folder)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
function folderAndFiles(){
  var files = [];
  var folderMap = {};

  var foldersParent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("names").next();
  var filesParent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("files").next();

  var filesIterator = filesParent.getFiles();
  var foldersIterator = foldersParent.getFolders();



  while(filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    var currentFile = filesIterator.next();
    files.push(currentFile);

  }

  while(foldersIterator.hasNext()) {
    var currentFolder =  foldersIterator.next();
    folderMap[currentFolder.getName()] = currentFolder;


  }

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var fileName = file.getName().replace('.jpg', '');
    var destinationFolder = folderMap[fileName];

    if (destinationFolder) {
      destinationFolder.addFile(files[i]);
      filesParent.removeFile(file);
      Logger.log("Moved");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that you'll want to traverse the folders with a recursive function.

Comment: Start separating your logic into reusable functions. Your code knows how to get the subfolders of a folder, so you just need to run that logic with a new parent. Your code then just needs to update the condition for moving a file from "names match" to "name parts match". Where is your attempt at modifying the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to accomplish your goals:

```js
function sortFiles() {
//  var folders = Drive.Files.list({
//    "q": "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
//    "fields": "items(title, id)"
//  });
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();  
//  var files = Drive.Files.list({
//    "q": "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false",
//    "fields": "items(title, id)"
//  });
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var folderIDs = [];
  var folderNames = [];
  var fileIDs = [];
  var fileNames = [];

  do {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderNames.push(folder.getName());
    folderIDs.push(folder.getId());
  } while (folders.hasNext());

  do {
    var file = files.next();
    fileNames.push(file.getName());
    fileIDs.push(file.getId());
  } while (files.hasNext());

  for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < folderNames.length; j++) {
      if (folderNames[j].search(fileNames[i]) > -1) {
        var oldFileParents = DriveApp.getFileById(fileIDs[i]).getParents();
        DriveApp.getFolderById(folderIDs[j]).addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(
          fileIDs[i]));
        if (oldFileParents.hasNext()) {
          do {
            oldFileParents.next().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(fileIDs[i]));
          } while (oldFileParents.hasNext());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Based on your comment I have updated the code to only use the [DriveApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) and no [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference). For future reference, I have commented the API calls to the method [`Files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) that I used to gather every file and folder (except the ones on the recycle bin).

The code will first use the methods [`.getFolders()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfolders) and [`.getFiles(`)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles) to gather all the folders and files of your Drive. It will later create two arrays per folders and files: one for IDs and other for names. Then, the names array are iterated looking for coincidences. After one coincidence is found, it will record the current folder(s) of the file with the methods [`.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)[`.getParents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html#getparents). We need to use this approach because a single file can be inside different folders of Drive.

So the final steps are going to be: first, gather the current folder(s) of the file. After that, we shall include the file into the new folder. And finally, we must delete the parent(s) folder previously saved on the first step.

Please, write back to me again if you need further help or clarifications.

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for this! I ran the code and initially got an error on the drive function but changed it to driveapp. Now im getting this error "TypeError: Cannot call method "list" of undefined. (line 2, file "Code")" Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi there @Richhawk106! I just updated my answer to only use DriveApp. Give a look to the new code to see if it can help you.

Comment: Hi! thank you! I'm struggling with moving the files. I'm trying to compare the two arrays but when I log them out to check if it's working nothing shows?

Comment: Hi @Richhawk106! Don’t feel obligated to edit anything, just copy and paste the full code. I already tested it and it works as described. Where are you logging the arrays? If they are empty it may show that they have not been populated yet.